# WCF - Client callback vs. polling for "keep list of subscribers"

Tags: c#, .net, wcf

I want to create a simple client-server example in WCF. I did some testing with callbacks, and it works fine so far. I played around a little bit with the following interface:

```
[ServiceContract(SessionMode = SessionMode.Required, CallbackContract = typeof(IStringCallback))]
public interface ISubscribeableService
{
    [OperationContract]
    void ExecuteStringCallBack(string value);

    [OperationContract]
    ServerInformation Subscribe(ClientInformation c);

    [OperationContract]
    ServerInformation Unsubscribe(ClientInformation c);
}
```

Its a simple example. a little bit adjusted. You can ask the server to "execute a string callback" in which case the server reversed the string and calls all subscribed client callbacks.

Now, here comes the question: If I want to implement a system where all clients "register" with the server, and the server can "ask" the clients if they are still alive, would you implement this with callbacks (so instead of this "stringcallback" a kind of TellTheClientThatIAmStillHereCallback). By checking the communication state on the callback I can also "know" if a client is dead. Something similar to this:

```
Subscribers.ForEach(delegate(IStringCallback callback)
                    {
                        if (((ICommunicationObject)callback).State == CommunicationState.Opened)
                        {
                            callback.StringCallbackFunction(new string(retVal));
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            Subscribers.Remove(callback);
                        }
                    });
```

My problem, put in another way:

- The server might have 3 clients
- Client A dies (I pull the plug of the laptop)
- The server dies and comes back online
- A new client comes up

So basically, would you use callbacks to verify the "still living state" of clients, or would you use polling and keep track "how long I havent heard of a client"...

Comment: How are you connecting to the WCF Sever?  Are you using TCP?  That would change how to implement a pooling.

Answer (score 3):

You can detect most changes to the connection state via the `Closed`, `Closing`, and `Faulted` events of `ICommunicationObject`.  You can hook them at the same time that you set up the callback.  This is definitely better than polling.

IIRC, the `Faulted` event will only fire **after** you actually try to use the callback (unsuccessfully).  So if the Client just disappears - for example, a hard reboot or power-off - then you won't be notified right away.  But do you need to be?  And if so, why?

A WCF callback might fail at any time, and you always need to keep this in the back of your mind.  Even if both the client and server are fine, you might still end up with a faulted channel due to an exception or a network outage.  Or maybe the client went offline sometime between your last poll and your current operation.  The point is, as long as you code your callback operations defensively (which is good practice anyway), then hooking the events above is usually enough for most designs.  If an error occurs for any reason - including a client failing to respond - the `Faulted` event will kick in and run your cleanup code.

This is what I would refer to as the passive/lazy approach and requires less coding and network chatter than polling or keep-alive approaches.

Comment: This is what I've done whenever I've needed similar functionality (which is somewhat frequent).

Answer (score 2):

If you enable reliable sessions, WCF internally maintains a keep-alive control mechanism. It regularly checks, via hidden infrastructure test messages, if the other end is still there. The time interval of these checks can be influenced via the ReliableSession.InactivityTimeout property. If you set the property to, say, 20 seconds, then the ICommunicationObject.Faulted event will be raised about 20 to 30 (maximum) seconds after a service breakdown has occurred on the other side.

If you want to be sure that client applications always remain "auto-connected", even after temporary service breakdowns, you may want to use a worker thread (from the thread pool) that repeatedly tries to create a new proxy instance on the client side, and calls a session-initiating operation, after the Faulted event has been raised there.

As a second approach, since you are implementing a worker thread mechanism anyway, you might also ignore the Faulted event and let the worker thread loop during the whole lifetime of the client application. You let the thread repeatedly check the proxy state, and try to do its repair work whenever the state is faulted.

Using the first or the second approach, you can implement a service bus architecture (mediator pattern), guaranteeing that all client application instances are constantly ready to receive "spontaneous" service messages whenever the service is running.

Of course, this only works if the reliable session "as such" is configured correctly to begin with (using a session-capable binding, and applying the ServiceContractAttribute.SessionMode, ServiceBehaviorAttribute.InstanceContextMode, OperationContractAttribute.IsInitiating, and OperationContractAttribute.IsTerminating properties in meaningful ways).

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar situation using WCF and callbacks.  I did not want to use polling, but I was using a "reilable" protocol, so if a client died, then it would hang the server until it timed out and crashed.

I do not know if this is the most correct or elegant solution, but what I did was create a class in the service to represent the client proxy.  Each instance of this class contained a reference to the client proxy, and would execute the callback function whenever the server set the "message" property of the class.  By doing this, when a client disconnected, the individual wrapper class would get the timeout excetpion, and remove itself from the server's list of listeners, but the service would not have to wait for it.  This doesn't actually answer your question about determining if the client is alive, but it is another way of structuring the service to addrss the issue.  If you needed to know when a client died, you would be able to pick up when the client wrapper removed itself from the listener list.

Answer (score 0):

I have not tried to use WCF callbacks over the wire but i have used them for interprocess communication. I was having a problem where call of the calls that were being sent were ending up on the same thread and making the service dead lock when there were calls that were dependant on the same thread.

This may apply to the problem that you are currently have so here is what I had to do to fix the problem.

Put this attribute onto the server and client of the WCF server implemetation class

```
[ServiceBehavior(ConcurrencyMode = ConcurrencyMode.Multiple)]
public class WCFServerClass
```

The ConcurrencyMode.Multiple makes each call process on its own thread which should help you with the server locking up when a client dies until it timesout.

I also made sure to use a Thread Pool on the client side to make sure that there were no threading issues on the client side